# Ubuntu 12.10 - Resolution stuck at 1024x768 using Open Source Radeon Driver

Tags: ati, xorg, display, resolution, radeon

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 with an ATI Radeon HD5670 card.

I currently have the open source [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) driver. I've been using this driver interchangeably with the Radeon open source driver since fglrx seems to give me a lot of freezes. So I can't really use proprietary drivers, the Radeon driver seems to be stable for me, the resolution is the only problem.

The resolution is stuck at 1024x768, where my monitor's native resolution is 1366x768. How do I enable that resolution? Going to System Settings > Display only gives me 800x600 and 1024x768 by the way.

And just another question, how do I know if xorg-edgers driver is enabled? When I run `sudo lshw -c video`, I still see the radeon driver.

```
configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Running `xrandr` gave me this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
..
DVI-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
```

So following the guide, I typed in the following:

`cvt 1366 768 60`

`xrandr --newmode "1366x768_60.00" 85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync`

xrandr now gives me this line:

```
1366x768_60.00 (0x178)   85.2MHz
```

But I'm still not able to execute the add command `xrandr --add-mode DVI-0 1366x768`, it just shows me the usage page for xrandr.

Comment: Try instaling proprietary drivers. You can do this from SystemSettings>SoftwareSources or by installing fglrx package.

Comment: @rafalcieslak I've already tried using proprietary drivers, but as I've mentioned, they do not work well for me (freezes/hangs/glitches).

Answer (score 3):

If I'm correct in understanding your question: you are using the radeon driver in the xserver-xorg-video-ati package from the xorg-edgers PPA.  If this is the case, then you are still using the radeon driver (as you should be).

You can add a new video mode (resolution) by doing the following.  Use `$ xrandr` to determine the video output in use.  Then, `# xrandr --addmode [OUTPUT] [MODE]`.  For example, I would put `# xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1920x1080`.  This is taken from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions).

EDIT: For the sake of completeness, a new mode needed to be created before adding the mode to the device.  The mode then needs to be switched to.  All of this is covered in the link.

Comment: The version of radeon driver you use is listed at the bottom of `$ man radeon`.

Comment: the `xrandr --add-mode` command still does not work for me. Am I missing something? I've updated the question with more details. Thanks.

Comment: You have successfully added the mode.  Now you need to associate is with the card via --add-mode (e.g `# xrandr --add-mode DVI-0 1366x768_60.00`) and switch to it with --output and --mode (e.g `# xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1366x768_60.00`).  Note that you need superuser privileges to switch modes.

Comment: Unfortunately `xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1366x768_60.00` gives me `xrandr: cannot find mode 1366x768_60.00`

Comment: I looked through my xrandr outputs and there is nothing with a dash.  Are you sure it is DVI-0 and not DVI0?

Comment: Yup, I double checked it, it's DVI-0, output is exactly like what I posted in the question update.

Comment: _facepalm_...There is no dash in --addmode...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6289/discussion-between-astex-and-mumble)